# Unread e-mail in Office 365

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office, unread-mail

With Office 365. I would like to know how I can obtain a file, or list of all user's unread e-mail count, not necessarily the detail. I understand this is a moving target. I'm fine with that. I'm comfortable with PowerShell, but not an expert. If not an answer, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is that user you? If not then you should be able to do that as something something data protection.

Answer (score 1):

The current way to do this is via the [MS Graph api](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-mailfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). There are PS modules that make it easier like [Microsoft.Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/installation). A good place to start is with a request like:

```text
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UserId}/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=isRead ne true&$count=true
```